# How can I use virtual users in "write list" and "read list" in samba?

Tags: linux, samba, file-sharing

Suppose I don't want to create effective users/group for my users (samba server as share server), and I need to create a share for them.

**Question :** How can I use `write list`, `read list`, `valid user` and so on without `UNIX effective user/group account`? (with virtual users)

Comment: what is your ultimate requirement?

Comment: Sure , you setup PeoFTP, you can add virtual user with ftppasswd command, i need same system.

Comment: ftppass for samba?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with v4, samba does no longer require the use of local UNIX accounts. If you're using samba v4, then you can use `samba-tool` to add a new user that's not present as a UNIX user:

```
samba-tool user add USERNAME-HERE
```

Comment: impossible to install samba 4.

Comment: What you ask for is impossible with samba3, so you're out of luck...

Answer (score 1):

You could just map the users accounts to two generic users accounts, one for reading and the other for writing. This uses a user.map file.

OR

You could try using winbind and map the Windows group to a UNIX group and just have one group for writing and another for reading.

First hit on google: http://www.brentnorris.net/samba2005.html#winbind

I have tested winbind on AIX & HP-UX in the past - we didn't implement it due to a number of problems. On a Linux you might have better luck.