# samba share subdirectory prevent rename/delete operation

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, samba, file-sharing

I have a samba share (ArchLinux with kernel `Linux comp001 3.18.7-2-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 12:53:57 MST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux` and samba version `Samba version 4.1.16`)mounted in `/mnt/data/`, that is working just fine:

```
/mnt/data/
|-- 3145_Tv.dtv
|-- 3145_Ubat.dtv
|-- 3145_h.dtv
`-- setting
    `-- map.ini
```

Now, I must upgrade samba configuration to following demands:

1. Directory `setting` must be accessible. THIS IS WORKING.
2. Directory `setting` must have disabled operations of rename and delete. WHATEVER I DO I HAVEN'T SUCCEDED IN THIS TASK.

Here is `/etc/samba/smb.conf` configuration file chunk that relates to shares:

```
[data]
    security = user
    comment = PiDaq data
    read only = no
;   locking = no
    path = /mnt/data
;    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 0222
    directory mask = 0033

[settings]
    security = user
    read only = yes
    path = /mnt/data/settings
    browseable = no
;    create mask = 0222
;    directory mask = 0033
```

Here is also output of `smbstatus` command:

```
Samba version 4.1.16
PID     Username      Group         Machine                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1075      user         user         192.168.0.120 (ipv4:192.168.0.120:51273)

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------
data         1075   192.168.0.120  Fri Feb 13 11:30:29 2015

Locked files:
Pid          Uid        DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1075         1002       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /mnt/data   .   Fri Feb 13 11:30:28 2015
1075         1002       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /mnt/data   .   Fri Feb 13 11:31:04 2015
1075         1002       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /mnt/data   setting   Fri Feb 13 11:31:04 2015
```

How do I accomplish task 2? Is this samba question at all or is this os permissions problem, becuase I am getting nowhere with this ...

Comment: You use samba4, So you can virtual user, Then read the http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156502/how-can-i-use-virtual-users-in-write-list-and-read-list-in-samba

Comment: Under `[global]` add `writeable = no`.

Comment: @DevNull, it does not work.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, what do you mean by "So you can virtual user"?

Comment: Samba 3 uses effective user/group , When you use virtual user then don't need to /etc/passwwd and /etc/groups , It improve your security and convenience your work.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, but I have Samba version `4.1.16`.

Comment: I explain you it's better to use virtual user.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, will try with virtual users.